# How to split input string in a LaTeX command?

Tags: strings, comma-separated-list

I would like a new command: \myfunc{string}, where string is something like: "a,b,x,y,x" and the effect of the command should be the following:
`\func{a}\func{b}\func{x}\func{y}\func{x}`, where `\func{}` is another predefined function. How to do this?

Answer (score 17):

This is very easy with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\func}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\func}{m}{%
  \fbox{#1} % a space follows
}

\begin{document}

\myfunc{a,b,c,x,y,z}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\func` can be defined in whatever way you like, also with `\newcommand`. What's important is that it has one argument.

You can also add code before `\ProcessList{#1}{\func}` and after it.

Note that you're not restricted to commas as separators, because you specify it at definition time.

Another advantage is that `\SplitList` automatically trims leading and trailing spaces around items, so the output from

```
\myfunc{ a , b,c ,x,y , z }
```

will be the same, contrary to other lower level approaches.

Answer (score 14):

LaTeX has a built in command for iterating over comma separated lists:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfunc[1]{\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\func{\tmp}}}
\makeatother

\let\func\fbox

\begin{document}

\myfunc{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use for loop on comma separated list if parameter of \myfunc is another function. So: \def \someVar {a, b, c}   then \myfunc{\someVar} In this case all variable is considered a one item

Comment: @Dmytro `\expandafter\myFunc\expandafter{\someVar}`