# Need help for macro to split a string and put the substrings into temp variables

Tags: strings

I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\tableData[2]{string1,string2,string3}{string4}

\newcommand*{\String1}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\String2}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\String3}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\String4}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

 \String1 
 ..
 \String4

\end{document}
```

So, i have two parameters, but i want to split the commaseparated strings in the first parameter and put it in the variables. How to do this with build-in-command or is it a better way to work with a package?

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225919/how-to-split-input-string-in-a-latex-command) already, but i want to put the different strings in different variables, not in `\fbox` or something else...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Note that `\String1`, `\String2`, `\String3`, and `\String4` are *not* valid TeX macro names. You probably need to consider naming them `\StringA`, `\StringB`, `\StringC`, and `\StringD`.

Comment: @Mico I'll consider this, thank you, it should be an example for my problem.

Comment: why `{string1,string2,string3}{string4}` and not `{string1,string2,string3,string4}`?

Comment: you can try this `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\def\tableData #1,#2,#3,#4{%
\def\stringA{#1}%
\def\stringB{#2}%
\def\stringC{#3}%
\def\stringD{#4}}
\begin{document}
\tableData string1,string2,string3,{string4}
\stringA

\stringB

\stringC

\stringD
\end{document}`

Comment: @touhami: The 2nd argument is strange indeed ;-)

Comment: @touhami, i will get more parameters as seen in the example and they will be grouped, so i get 12 or 13 values in the end... And so, i need a solution, that is not restricted to nine parameters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the `clist` facilities by `expl3` and a `\GetString{number}` macro which fetches the relevant string with number `number` instead a bunch of `\StringOne` etc. routines

**Edit**: Please note that the list container `\g_samhoff_string_clist` is cleared each time `\tableData` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_samhoff_string_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\tableData}{mm}{
  \clist_clear:N \g_samhoff_string_clist % Clearing the list
  \clist_set:Nn{\g_samhoff_string_clist}{#1}
  \clist_put_right:Nn{\g_samhoff_string_clist}{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetString}{m}{
  \clist_item:Nn{\g_samhoff_string_clist}{#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\tableData{one, two, three}{four}

Now the data:

\GetString{1}

\GetString{2}

\GetString{3}

\GetString{4}

\end{document}
```

Explanation:

- `\tableData` is defined to be a macro with two mandatory arguments, therefore {mm}
- The first argument is supposed to have the comma-separated-value list.
- `\clist_new:N \g_samhoff_string_clist` defines a new csv - list variable globally with name g_samhoff_string_clist. (`\g` stands for *global*)
- At the begin of `\tableData`, clear the list: `\clist_clear:N`
- Now store the first parameter (the clist!) with `\clist_set:Nn`
- Append the 2nd parameter to right side of `\g_samhoff_string_clist}` with `\clist_put_right:Nn`

With `\clist_item{\g_samhoff_string_clist}{2}` for example it's possible to fetch the 2nd item in the list.

`\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are necessary to make the new macro names possible (and other stuff)

Comment: @egreg: I know: I've omitted the <module> ;-) I'll change

Comment: @egreg: Better? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you, that works for now, but i didn't understand the entire code and the documentary of the xparse-package is unfortunately not clear for me.. I think my english is not good enough for that. 
So, ist it possible to explain the lines from `\ExplSyntaxOn` to `\ExplSyntaxOff` ?

Comment: @SamHoff: See the explanations

Comment: thank you, it helps a lot and i'm going to understand it a little bit. Only one question: when i get more arguments in table data, like `\tableData{a,s,d}{q,w,e,r}{j,k,l}{t,z}`, then i only have to change the mandatory argument to `{mmmm}` or did i misunderstood this..??

Comment: @SamHoff: Yes, but I don't recommend this. It's no good way, in my point of view for this `{a,b,c,d}` stuff

Comment: oh, okay... :-/
So, did you have a better approach for that?

Comment: @SamHoff: In my opinion the `{a,b,c,d}{e,f,g}{...}` etc. approach is not really useful unless you explicitly explain why this is should be done this way and no other

Comment: i will get the table data like this 

*\row{day, date}{come, go,hours,days}{project}* 

from an external program. This program commits 30 or 40 records and then i have to create a time sheet in LaTex. 
I also think, that this is not useful, but that's the way I get the data. So, if you have a soltution in a completely different way for me, I would be deeply grateful.